# How do I make a mute command? Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am here today asking a question on mute commands. I have been trying to find a tutorial but couldn't. Most videos or articles state that you need a role id but, I want to make it so if it creates a muted role in the server and then it keeps using the role it created. Sort of like Dyno's mute command. Is there a way to do that? Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have made a simple way to create a role each time you use the mute command. You would need to create a role called `Mute` or whatever you want it to be with the role permissions prior setting it up. Otherwise, but a more extensive way would be to store the role id from the server in a database so you wouldn't have to create the role and the bot would only make it once, then apply the role, but it's something you can find out.

```py
@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):

    guild = ctx.guild
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Mute')
   
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await member.send("You were muted for reason: " + reason)

    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been muted! With reasoning: ' + reason)
```

You can add extra precautions that the bot would check when a user uses the command, or who can use it; below the bot can check if the user has a lower role they are trying to mute, and checks if a member was provided to mute.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):

    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send(f"You can only use this moderation on a member below you")
        return

    if member == None:
        await ctx.send(f'You must provide a member to mute')
        return

    guild = ctx.guild
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Mute')

    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await member.send("You were muted for reason: " + reason)

    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been muted! With reasoning: ' + reason)
```

It's quite a basic example, but it's also good to attempt or leave some code that you have tried in your question. As this helps to understand what you want and more specifically or you have at least shown evidence.

Answer (score 0):

So I made it that everytime bot joins a server, It creates a "Muted" role and stores it in a database i.e JSON file you can change it to a better storing system as you want.

So for database system, you need `json` module. Import it first where you are importing other modules i.e `discord`, `discord.ext` etc.

```py
import json
```

Then we will create a `on_guild_join` event that will fire when bot is added in a guild. In this event, we will create a role named "Muted" and for that role, we will disable the `send_messages` and `add_reactions` permissions so that anyone with that role cannot send messages nor add reactions.
Once we created the role we can get the role using it's name using `utils` from `discord` module.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    permissions= discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, add_reactions=False)
    await guild.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=permissions, color=discord.Color("red")
```

Once we created the role we can get the role using it's name using `utils` from `discord` module.

```py
role= discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
```

Now, that we have Muted role setup we need to store it in our Database so we can get it when some calls the `mute` command, So create a new file in your working directory named `muted_roles.json` and in that file put curly braces like this: `{}`. Why we did that? Well JSON file needs curly braces and JSON module cannot manipulate those files that do not have those braces.
 Then getting back to code, here comes the `json` module in the play.

```py
with open("muted_roles.json", "r") as f:
    muted_roles = json.load(f)
muted_roles[str(guild.id)] = str(role.id)

with open("muted_roles.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(muted_roles, f, indent=4)
```

Now when the bot will get a new guild, you will notice in your Json file that there's the guild ID with the role ID. Just like a Python Dictionary. Somewhat like this:

```json
{
    "GUILD ID" : "ROLE ID"
}
```

Now let's head over to the next step of making command;

```py
@client.command()

async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, reason = "Unspecified"):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.send("Please do mention the person you want to mute!")
        return
    
    elif member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role: # credits for this to @Cohen
        await ctx.send(f"You can only use this moderation on a member below you")
        return
   
   else:
        with open("muted_roles.json", "r") as f:
            muted_roles = json.load(f)
        
        role = ctx.guild.get_role(int(muted_roles))
        await member.add_roles(role)

        await member.send(f"You have been muted.\nReason: {reason}")
        await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been muted.\nReason: {reason}")
```

Final code:

```py
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client= commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    permissions= discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, add_reactions=False)
    await guild.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=permissions, color=discord.Color("red")
    role= discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

    with open("muted_roles.json", "r") as f:
        muted_roles = json.load(f)
    muted_roles[str(guild.id)] = str(role.id)

    with open("muted_roles.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(muted_roles, f, indent=4)

    
    @client.command()

    async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, reason = "Unspecified"):
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send("Please do mention the person you want to mute!")
            return
    
        elif member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role: # credits for this to @Cohen
            await ctx.send(f"You can only use this moderation on a member below you")
            return
   
        else:
            with open("muted_roles.json", "r") as f:
                muted_roles = json.load(f)
        
            role = ctx.guild.get_role(int(muted_roles))
            await member.add_roles(role)

            await member.send(f"You have been muted.\nReason: {reason}")
            await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been muted.\nReason: {reason}")


client.run("TOKEN")
```

...And mute command is done! Please read more about all the mentioned modules and other methods from given references it will help for better understanding.

[`json` Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) 
[`discord.Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20permissions#discord.Permissions)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding but I couldn't get this working. Could you elaborate more or attach a image of where everything goes?

Comment: @CollinFong Do you get any error messages? There are a lots of meaning of not working, can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: For some reason whenever I put the code in, the command below it (which it was working before) just says invalid syntax.

Comment: @CollinFong The code I put there was just for concept on how things work. You should check if there is a bracket missing in your actual code or something. Also, On what line the error is?

Comment: I have solved the error, there was a missing parenthesis. But now I have errors saying: [undefined name "guild"] in the code in the "with open" code.

Comment: Apparently your error is in `on_guild_join` event. Are you sure your indentation are correct? That role ID dumping code is actually part of `on_guild_join` event.

Comment: I am very certain everything is placed and indented correctly could you give me an example code of where everything goes? I might've put things in the wrong places...